# vimeo js api seekTo leaves the play/pause button visible

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I have a pro account and I have stripped everything off the player.  the play/pause button is of course fine but I want it to fade out after a second or so...

I built a little test player, to illustrate the issue. [HERE](http://sandbox.ravennainteractive.com/)

You can press play from the video or the external control. Once playing if you click the progress bar, that triggers a few calculations then seekTo the point in the video. This all works great.
The issue is that once you "seek" / click the progress bar, the pause button won't fade out.
I know I can't hide the play/pause button in favor of my own but this is pretty detrimental to the video having a huge button in the middle if the user seeks the middle...

I appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: Basically if you click the seek, it shows the play/pause, then if you hover the iframe and then leave it fades the play/pause back out

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the seek event (you already does in line 53 of your index.html player.addEvent('seek', onPlayProgress);) and place the following code to force the control to fadeOut after 2 seconds (you can play with it)

```
setTimeout(function(){  
              $('#player1').contents().find('#player > div.controls-wrapper').fadeOut()
         }, 2000);
```

Comment: Let me give that a try.